# Is it possible to recursively share folders (with all their content) in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, sharing

Say I have a folder on my Google Drive, which contains some files. If I share this folder with someone else (either as an editor or as a viewer), it will appear to them by default as an empty folder. They will only see the files I explicitly share with them. Conversely, if I delete someone from the list of collaborators on said folder, they will still have access to every file they could access before.

Of course, when I have to share many folders containing many files and even sub-folders with even one person, this becomes unwieldy.

Is there any way to recursively share a folder and all of its children objects in Google Drive?

Comment: Are you sure about that? When I share a folder everything under it is shared as well.

Comment: I am 100% sure about that, I've just checked.

Answer (score 2):

From a comment by [Maxim](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/131654/maxim):

> Currently (2016.08), if I share a folder with another person, all files inside this folder get shared as well, but not the subfolders. In other words, Google Docs sharing it is not recursive, indeed, (though not in the way @Fibonacci described this).

Comment: That really sucks :-( Is Google forcing its users to by GSuite Business with Shared drive?

Answer (score 1):

The permissions are inherited, however, in my experience, there can be significant delay (minutes) until the permissions are propagated down. Same for removing them.

Answer (score -1):

As of today, sharing a folder in Google Drive recursively shares all subfolders and files in it.

It is my observation.